# MongoDB sharding on all collections

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I used the following command for sharding all the collections in my databse:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collname){db.adminCommand( {
    shardCollection: collname , key: { _id : "hashed" } } ) } )
```

it went successful as it not prompted any error.But when I did getShardDistribution() on one of the collection of this database it prompted:

> "the collection is not sharded."

Comment: I have used two separate shards without creating replica sets of them as according to the Mongo documentation it is not necessary to use replica sets for shard servers. I have added those two shards to the mongos(query router) server too.

Comment: Did you enable sharding by `sh.enableSharding()`

Comment: yes I did that too but still.

Comment: Did you refresh the routing cache after creating shards using `db.adminCommand( { flushRouterConfig: "test.myShardedCollection" } );` and then try to run your `getShardDistribution() `. Also shw me how you running this command

Comment: You must deploy a ReplicaSet, see [Shards](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/): *As of MongoDB 3.6, shards must be deployed as a replica set to provide redundancy and high availability.*

Comment: Did you run the command on any system database like `admin`, `local` or `config`?

Comment: No I ran the command on the database on which I have to enable sharding

Comment: @QamberAli did you tried the command I mentioned above?

Comment: @QamberAli Have you created the index on the shard key field for each of the collections? This is a must, _before_ you run the `sh.shardCollection` command.

Comment: @Sohan can i apply loop for all collections in the command you mentioned above?

Comment: @prasad_ yes I did the indexing too.

Comment: @QamberAli I have not tried that, but I would suggest check if this works for few of your collections

Comment: If you can, please try sharding _one_ collection only in the sharded database - without using the for-loop. If it works for one collection, you will be sure for the rest of the collections.

Comment: @Sohan I tried the command you mentioned above, that too not worked for me.

Comment: @prasad_ if I am sharding one collection then its responding but not on the loop

Comment: Have you created indexes for all the collections? Verify once again.

Comment: What is the output of `db.adminCommand({ listShards: 1 })` ?

Comment: I was looking at this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-sharded-clusters/. Update your question with command to db.records.getShardDistribution();

Comment: `forEach` doesn't always return errors from other than the last iteration, using `map` for this in the future will at least let you see the success/failure of each step.